# Отображение Bitmap с альфа-каналом на Canvas'е

Tags: android, java, canvas

Здравствуйте. Как в ОС Android отрисовать на Canvas'e объект Bitmap из, скажем .PNG файла с альфа-каналом? Т.е. имеется некий рисунок в файле, и пустая область вокруг (на рисунке - белая) не должна отрисовываться. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит просто с помощью GIMP\Photoshop или других программ создать Alpha-канал и сохранить изображение в `*.png`?

Comment: А сами методы в API Android? Надо же как-то "выставить" этот альфа-канал у Bitmap'а?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29
Это не то?